# How to get a perfect match for a regexp pattern in Perl?

Tags: perl

**I've to match a regular-expression, stored in a variable:**

```
#!/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
my $expr = qr/\s*(\w+(\[\d+\])?)\s+(\w+(\[\d+\])?)/sx;
$str = "abcd[3] xyzg[4:0]";
if ($str =~ m/$expr/) {
    print "\n%%%%%%%%% $`-----$&-----$'\n";
}
else {
    print "\n********* NOT MATCHED\n";
}
```

But I'm getting the outout in $& as

```
%%%%%%%%% -----abcd[3] xyzg-----[4:0]
```

But expecting, it shouldn't go inside the if clause.
**What is intended is:**

```
if $str = "abcd xyzg" => %%%%%%%%% -----abcd xyzg-----            (CORRECT)
if $str = "abcd[2] xyzg" => %%%%%%%%% -----abcd[2] xyzg-----      (CORRECT)
if $str = "abcd[2] xyzg[3] => %%%%%%%%% -----abcd[2] xyzg[3]----- (CORRECT)
if $str = "abcd[2:0] xyzg[3] => ********* NOT MATCHED             (CORRECT)
if $str = "abcd[2:0] xyzg[3:0] => ********* NOT MATCHED           (CORRECT)
if $str = "abcd[2] xyzg[3:0]" => ********* NOT MATCHED            (CORRECT/INTENDED)
```

but output is `%%%%%%%%% -----abcd[2] xyzg-----[3:0]               (WRONG)`
OR better to say this is not intended.
In this case, it should/my_expectation go to the else block.
Even I don't know, why **$&** take a portion of the string (**abcd[2] xyzg**), and **$'** having **[3:0]**?
**HOW**?
It should match the full, not a part like the above. If it didn't, it shouldn't go to the *if* clause.

Can anyone please help me to change my $expr pattern, so that I can have what is intended?

Comment: Is this the smallest, simplest example of the pattern feature you're looking for? Because I'm just not following the question. Regexps do match perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

By default, Perl regexes only look for a matching *substring* of the given string.  In order to force comparison against the entire string, you need to indicate that the regex begins at the beginning of the string and ends at the end by using `^` and `$`:

```
my $expr = qr/^\s*(\w+(\[\d+\])?)\s+(\w+(\[\d+\])?)$/;
```

(Also, there's no reason to have the `/x` modifier, as your regex doesn't include any literal whitespace or `#` characters, and there's no reason for the `/s` modifier, as you're not using `.`.)

EDIT: If you don't want the regex to match against the entire string, but you want it to reject anything in which the matching portion is followed by something like "[0:0]", the simplest way would be to use lookahead:

```
my $expr = qr/^\s*(\w+(\[\d+\])?)\s+(\w+(\[\d+\]|(?=[^[\w])|$ ))/x;
```

This will match anything that takes the following form:

- beginning of the string (which your example in the comments seems to imply you want)
- zero or more whitespace characters
- one or more word characters
- optional: `[`, one or more digits, `]`
- one or more whitespace characters
- one or more word characters
- one of the following, in descending order of preference:

  - - `[`, one or more digits, `]`
  - - an empty string followed by (but not including!) a character that is neither `[` nor a word character (The exclusion of word characters is to keep the regex engine from succeeding on "`a[0] bc[1:2]`" by only matching "`a[0] b`".)
  - - end of string (A space is needed after the `$` to keep it from merging with the following `)` to form the name of a special variable, and this entails the reintroduction of the `/x` option.)

Do you have any more unstated requirements that need to be satisfied?

Comment: Think I do have more and more matching in $expr like: my $expr = qr/\s*(\w+(\[\d+\])?)\s+(\w+(\[\d+\])?)(....)?/sx; And I need to match till something matching exactly. Then what I need to do?

Comment: @GaurabBanerjee: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Let say my $expr is as follows: 

my $expr = qr/\s*(\w+(\[\d+\])?)\s+(\w+(\[\d+\])?)(\s+(\w+(\[\{\d+:\d+\}\]|\[\d+\])?)\s+(\w+(\[\{\d+:\d+\}\]|\[\d+\])?)((\s+\d+)?(\s+[\w\/ ]+)?(\s+\w+)?)?)?/sx;

 
and my input string is 

    $str = "abcd[2] xyzg[0] ghhh_in ghjj_out[9:0] 45"; 

then the OUTPUT is 

> %%%%%%%%% -----abcd[2] xyzg[0] ghhh_in ghjj_out-----[9:0] 45

but my EXPECTATION is 

> %%%%%%%%% -----abcd[2] xyzg[0]-----hhh_in ghjj_out[9:0] 45

What to do in this case. As I've told, I need a perfect matching till it have.

Comment: @Gau If that is an expectation of yours, you should add it to your question! That string has three fields, not two as you previously stated!

Comment: This string contains five fields:                                     $str = "abcd[2] xyzg[0] ghhh_in   ghjj_out[9:0]  45";

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is your regexp is wrong.
We can't fix it for you without you explaining what you need exactly, and the community is not going to write a regexp exactly for your purpose because that's just too localized a question that only helps you this one time.

You need to ask something more general about regexps that we can explain to you, that will help you fix your regexp, and help others fix theirs.

Here's my general answer when you're having trouble testing your regexp. Use a regexp tool, like the [regex buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) one.

So I'm going to give a specific answer about what you're overlooking here:
Let's make this example smaller:
Your pattern is `a(bc+d)?`. It will match: `abcd` `abccd` etc. While it will not match `bcd` nor `bzd` in the case of `abzd` it will match as matching only `a` because the whole group of `bc+d` is optional. Similarly it will match `abcbcd` as `a` dropping the whole optional group that couldn't be matched (at the second `b`).

Regexps will match as much of the string as they can and return a true match when they can match something and have satisfied the entire pattern. If you make something optional, they will leave it out when they have to including it only when it's present and matches.

Here's what you tried:
  `qr/\s*(\w+(\[\d+\])?)\s+(\w+(\[\d+\])?)/sx`
First, `s` and `x` aren't needed modifiers here.
Second, this regex can match:
Any or no whitespace followed by
a word of at least one alpha character followed by
optionally a grouped square bracketed number with at least one digit (eg [0] or [9999]) followed by
at least one white space followed by
a word of at least one alpha character followed by
optionally a square bracketed number with at least one digit.

Clearly when you ask it to match `abcd[0] xyzg[0:4]` the colon ends the `\d+` pattern but doesn't satisfy the `\]` so it backtracks the whole group, and then happily finds the group was optional. So by not matching the last optional group, your pattern has matched successfully.